# Split vs Strip in Python to remove redundant white space

Tags: python, string, list, split, strip

May I ask do I need to use strip() before split() to remove any redundant space in Python (and turn into a list after)?
For example:

```
string1 = '   a      b '
```

I want the result:

```
#list1=[a,b]
```

When I test I found out that `list1=string1.split()` is enough. But somehow my teacher say `string1.strip().split()` is needed. Maybe he is wrong?

Comment: Why does he say that? What research have you done?

Comment: I cannot come up with an example when `strip` + `split` works, but `split` alone doesn't. By default, `split` removes all the whitespace, so I think, he's wrong.

Comment: Sure, just `split()` works when you want to split by spaces, but for the general case, if you wanted to split on commas for example, you'd need to strip out leading and trailing whitespace. `"   abc,def   ".split(',') != "   abc,def   ".strip().split(",")`

Comment: Your teacher is probably thinking that you would use `string1.split(" ")` or doesn't know that `split()` or `split(None)` has a different behaviour that ignores leading/trailing spaces and treats consecutive spaces as a single separator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If *sep* is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

Which means, that the logic of `strip()` is already included into `split()`, so I think, your teacher is wrong. (Notice, that this will change in case if you're using a non-default separator.)

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

You are right (at least for the case of using the default split by whitespace). Leading and trailing as well as consecutive whitescapes are ignored, and since `.strip()` does nothing else than remove leading and trailing whitespaces, it will result in the same output here.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using:

```
string1 = '   a      b '
list1 = string1.strip().split()
print(list1)
```

and

```
string1 = '   a      b '
list1 = string1.split()
print(list1)
```

And they give the **same** result.

So using `strip()` isn't necessarily needed, as it will only remove the spaces at the start (leading whitespaces) and spaces at the end (trailing whitespaces).

Comment: _Lists automatically remove spaces from strings_ - lists have nothing to do with that.

Comment: @bereal I'm sorry, I didn't know that. Thank you for telling me.

Comment: Please update your answer per the comment by @bereal as the answer in its current state is inaccurate.